# How can I get more information about a unit?

Tags: xcom-2

In the previous XCOM game, when I had a unit selected (either friend or foe), I could bring up information about them. It would tell me current buffs, debuffs, etc that they had.

I haven't been able to find anything like this in XCOM 2. Does it exist?

Answer (score 9):

The presence of Buffs / Debuffs can be seen in the lower-right of each units' selection icon. For enemies, this is the icon you get when you have sight on them. For your own units, this is in the lower left, by their name.

Hovering over this icon will show what buffs/debuffs are currently active.

[image]